# Why am I getting an "undefined" text on my calculator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperand = '';
    this.clear();
  }
  clear() {
    this.previousOperandElement = '';
    this.currentOperandElement = '';
    this.operation = undefined;
  }

  delete() {

  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentOperand === '') return
    if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
      this.compute()
    }
    this.operation = operation;
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand;
    this.currentOperand = ''
  }

  compute() {
    let computation
    const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand);
    const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand);
    if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return
    switch (this.operation) {
      case '+':
        computation = prev + current
        break
      case '-':
        computation = prev - current
        break
      case '*':
        computation = prev * current
        break
      case '÷':
        computation = prev / current
        break
      default:
        return
    }
    this.currentOperand = computation;
    this.operation = undefined;
    this.previousOperand = '';
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
    this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = this.previousOperand;
    this.currentOperand = '';


  }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]');
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]');
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');

const calculator = new Calculator(currentOperandTextElement, previousOperandTextElement);

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.compute()
  calculator.updateDisplay();
})
```

```css
CSS
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #722f37, #caa181);
}

.calculator-grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}

.calculator-grid>button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}

.calculator-grid>button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}

.span-two {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.output {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: rgba(51, 35, 35, 0.397);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.output .previous-operand {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.output .current-operand {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale=1.0>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
    <button data-delete>DEL</button>
    <button data-operation>÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data operation>-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include some other information and details to the question. What is the exact issue, what are you stuck with, and what have you tried to solve it? And please reduce your code into a [mcve]. Also, read https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve and https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = this.previousOperand` is causing the "undefined" to show, since `this.previousOperand` is undefined. To fix it, add `this.previousOperand = ''` to your `constructor()` function.